# Laravel / Snappy: can not generate PDF or create folder

Tags: laravel, snappy

This is my code:

```
$offer = Offer::find($id);
$url = URL::to('/offers/view/' . $id . '/pdf');

PDF::loadFile($url)
    ->callSettings()
    ->save('/tisa/src/public/pdf/offer/Tisa-ponudba_'. $offer->code .'.pdf');
```

I am getting following error:

```
RuntimeException in AbstractGenerator.php line 517:
The output file's directory '/tisa/src/public/pdf/offer' could not be created.
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? I can not determine if a file can not be created or is the folder path?

Comment: I hope that folder exists and given proper permissions?

Comment: Folder exist. What would be proper permission?

Comment: give write permissions like `sudo chmod -R 777 folder`

Comment: Still the same error. Does it need to be full server path? I am running this on virtual machine.

Comment: `/tisa/src/public/pdf/offer/Tisa-ponudba_'. $offer->code .'.pdf` it will take tisa as a base directory. path is incorrect

Comment: That was it, thank for your effort.